# Share your "My Site" screenshots

Tags: 2007, my-site

I'm setting up My Site and am looking for ideas so I can get others in the company to be excited about what they can do with their sites.

Would you guys that have put some time and energy into yours mind sharing some screenshots that I can use for inspiration?

Thanks in advance!

We're in a SharePoint 2007 environment but would like to see any and all.

Comment: since this is more of a "poll" rather than a question, I've converted your question to a community wiki. Potentially, it could be closed but I would like to get input from other people to see if they consider it constructive before I do. More info http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-should-we-handle-poll-the-best-resource-list-style-questions

Comment: Ours became modified to a Personalization page since we are using SharePoint for a community site, so its very customized and unfortunately not share-able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine's uber awesome, Daily Dilbert RSS feed pulled into my My Site.

On a more serious note, they aren't heavily utilized here.  We typically promote them as a sandbox or play area for users to become more familiar with how Sharepoint works.